# set userInteractionEnabled false in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to set userInteractionEnabled false on the Image component in RN?

Asking it because need to implement the design below. There is a blur overlay on the right side. We want the text under it still can handle click, so need set the blur image userInteractionEnabled false.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `userInteractionEnabled` in react-native is the `touchEvents` prop for views.

You can set it to "none" on your Image and it will not intercept touches anymore.
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents

Comment: after much searching I found nothing for "touchEvents" and that page is a 404.

Answer (score 4):

is very easy.

`<View accessible={false} pointerEvents='none'>`