# RN View userInteractionEnabled = false equivalent

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to set a view's `userInteractionEnabled = false` in a `View` component to handle touch event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068392/set-userinteractionenabled-false-in-react-native